# DataTables - How to order a column using custom condition?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

In one of my PHP based Project, I need to order a **column** using custom condition or custom order rather than **DataTable's** default ordering (ascending or descending).

I have four **statuses**: Urgent, High, Medium, Low

---

The custom order I want is:

During ascending it will be: Low, Medium, High, Urgent
During descending it will be: Urgent, High, Medium, Low

---

So, after searching on **DataTables**, I found a solution that works OK in **DataTables**. Here it is [slightly customized to meet my criteria]:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['ticket-priority-pre'] = function ( d ) {
    switch ( d ) {
        case 'Low'      :   return 1;
        case 'Medium'   :   return 2;
        case 'High'     :   return 3;
        case 'Urgent'   :   return 4;
    }
    return 0;
};

$( document ).ready( function() {
    //initializing datatables
    $('#ticketList').DataTable({
        "paging"    :   false,
        "info"      :   false,
        "searching" :   false,
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "type": "ticket-priority",
            "targets": -1
        } ]
    });
});
```

---

But the order I got is:

Ascending: High, Low, Medium, Urgent
Descending: Urgent, Medium, Low, High

---

For some unknown reason *Low* and *High* did the wrong order.

Can anyone help me to fix the issue in my code or able to provide a solution?

- Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from the next example:

https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/sorting_auto.html

I think, you will need to do this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.detect.unshift(
    function ( d ) {
        return (d === 'Low' || d === 'Medium' || d === 'High' || d === 'Urgent') ?
            'ticket-priority' :
            null;
    }
);

$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['ticket-priority-pre'] = function ( d ) {
    switch ( d ) {
        case 'Low'      :   return 1;
        case 'Medium'   :   return 2;
        case 'High'     :   return 3;
        case 'Urgent'   :   return 4;
    }
    return 0;
};

$( document ).ready( function()
{
    // Initializing datatables.

    $('#ticketList').DataTable({
        "paging"    :   false,
        "info"      :   false,
        "searching" :   false,
        "order"     : [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "type": "ticket-priority",
            "targets": -1
        } ]
    });
});
```